# How to I rewrite a directory in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, model-view-controller, url-rewriting

I have a website with a url example.com/public/page
I would like to rewrite it into example.com/page.

I have tried this solution:

```
location /public/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/public/(.+)$ /public/index.php?url=$1 last;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I have also tried putting `rewrite ^/public/(.+)$ /public/index.php?url=$1 last;` in the `location /` block and removing the if statement but it still doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Instead set root to public directly `root  /var/www/example.com/public;`

Comment: @User863 Can't believe I haven't thought about it all along. Thank you so much. It worked